# without page refresh dropdown selected option value to get data form api vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Here axios api in service folder selct dropdown values  to set localstorage (id)
then get api response data is fine.but my problem only page refresh to get the data.how to without page refresh to gat data

@change="onChange" to change drop down values to set id in localstorage .then get id to data its working fine.but dropdown to select values only show page refresh

```js
const dropdownItems = ref(items);
const dropdownItem = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {    
  ApiService.getStores().then((data) => {
    data.forEach((value) => {
      items.push({ name: value.shop,value:value.id });
    });
  });
});

const onChange = event => {
  localStorage.setItem('id',event.value);
}

<Dropdown
  id="state"
  v-model="dropdownItem"
  :options="dropdownItems"
  :filter="true"
  optionLabel="name"
  optionValue="value"
  @change="onChange"
/>
```

api.service.js

```
const id = localStorage.getItem('id');
axios.get(API_URL+'/product/all?id='+id)
```

how to trigger api.service.js

Comment: please, re-write what is your issue. is unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Try making `dropdownItems` a computed value that returns `items`.

`const dropdownItems = computed(() => items)`

This will ensure that when `items` is changed, the variable `dropdownItems` is re-computed.

Comment: @change="onChange" to change drop down values to set id in localstorage .then get id  to data its working fine.but dropdown to select values only show page refresh